# How to select a server when ntpd is syncing by a linux server?

Tags: linux, ntpd, ntpdate

The following is my ntpd configure file. I have no idea, which one ntpd will choice while it's syncing?

```
/etc/ntp.conf
server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
server pool.ntp.org
```

Answer (score 6):

The NTP daemon uses an algorithm that will evaluate the time returned by all the listed servers.

You can see it at work with the `ntpq -p` command.

Comment: @aboutstudy Please consider accepting helpful answers. It provides encouragement to the people answering your questions. :)

Answer (score 3):

NTP will look at the stratums, latency, and so on.  It will select the server with the best time.

Since you are using pool.ntp.org entries and nothing else it really doesn't matter to much.  It will select some server out of the pool.

Keep in mind that it will get time from the other servers as well to make sure that what it is getting from he master is not garbage.  So it isn't exclusively using a single server.

Answer (score 2):

ntpd will sync with multiple servers to get more accurate results.